# Go nested map iteration

Tags: go

I'm trying to iterate over the entire keys of a map `eventObj`, including the nested objects inside it and check every key and value for further actions.

So, if I see another nested map I will need to iterate it as well.

I've tried to do so with the comparison of the type to `map[string]interface` or `map[string]interface{}` but it seems to be a syntax error.

My question is how to identify a nested map?

(note that I can have several nested maps)

```
func lookForEmailsInEvent(eventObj map[string]interface {}) {
for key, _ := range eventObj {
    valueType := reflect.TypeOf(eventObj[key]).String()
    fmt.Printf("%v : %v\n", key, valueType)

    if valueType == map[string]interface {
        lookForEmailsInEvent(eventObj[key])
    } else if key == "email" {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

}

This is the value of `eventObj` (screenshot from terminal):
[image]

Comment: You are mixing up basic types left and right, and on top of that you're using reflection, and you are using it incorrectly. Don't write code like this, take the Go Tour please.

Comment: @mkopriva correct. i meant map and not struct

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to recurse through the nested data:

```
func lookForEmailsInEvent(eventObj map[string]any) {
    for k, v := range eventObj {
        if v, ok := v.(map[string]any); ok {
            lookForEmailsInEvent(v)
        } else if k == "email" {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

This code uses a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to determine if a value is a `map[string]any`.

[Type assertions are covered](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15) in the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1).